# DataServiceRequestException was unhandled by user code. An error occurred while processing this request

Tags: azure, exception

`DataServiceRequestException` was unhandled by user code. An error occurred while processing this request.

This is in relation to the previous post I added

```
public void AddEmailAddress(EmailAddressEntity emailAddressTobeAdded)
{
    AddObject("EmailAddress", emailAddressTobeAdded);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Again the code breaks and gives a new exception this time. Last time it was Storage Client Exception, now it is `DataServiceRequestException`. Code breaks at `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, solution is same. CamelCasing is not supported. So the code works if "EmailAddress" is changed to "Emailaddress" or "emailaddress"
More details 
http://weblogs.asp.net/chanderdhall/archive/2010/07/10/dataservicerequestexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-an-error-occurred-while-processing-this-request.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because you've tagged this with "azure" and "table," I'm going to assume this code results in a call to Windows Azure tables.  If so, I can assure you that camel casing table names is indeed supported.  However, the string you pass to AddObject has to match a table that you've created, so make sure the code where you create the table is using the same casing.